# Problems with Polish chars CodenameOne and WebService

Tags: web-services, encoding, codenameone

I have a web app with UTF8 encoding deployed on apache-tomcat. Sending data in servlet parameter with polish chars in such as "ąęćńźżół" is not a problem. They are interpreted fine. But while sending back string to CodenameOne all i get is Ä? Ä? ?? ?? Ä? ??.

Servlet code:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
try {
String ID;
String answer = "no answer";      
ID = request.getParameter("Id");
answer="ą ę ż ź ć ó";
//this is an answer to the client – Codename one          
out.print(answer);                        
} finally {           
out.close();
}
}
```

CodenameOne code:

```
response = "empty";
try {           
//the NetworkManager object
NetworkManager networkManager = NetworkManager.getInstance();
networkManager.start();
networkManager.addErrorListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    NetworkEvent n = (NetworkEvent) evt;
    n.getError().printStackTrace();                        
}});
//ConnectionRequest object   
ConnectionRequest request = new ConnectionRequest() {
int chr;
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();                   
protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
//reading the answer                      
while ((chr = input.read()) != -1){
sb.append((char) chr);
}
response = sb.toString();                                           
response = response.trim();
}  
protected void handleException(Exception err) {
//An error occured - show a message:
Dialog.show("Yikes!!", "Are you connected to the internet? Check your connection", "Ok",  null);
}
};

request.setUrl("http://localhost:8080/FirstOneTomcat/Response"); //servlet calling
request.setPost(false);
request.addArgument("ID","ńćżźóąę"); //sending a the parameter Id to the servlet                                  
} catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}                
while(response.equals("empty")) {
//waiting for the answer from the serlvet or jsp server
System.out.println("No response from server");
}
//set the label with the information from the server
findLabelKom().setText(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are embedding polish into the server source code which means the compiler needs to pick the encoding and it can do anything. Use either the `native2ascii` tool to convert your polish to \u notation (notice that you didn't enter UTF but rather in polish encoding).

Or you can configure your IDE's/Compilers encoding when compiling source code.

Comment: I embedded polish characters just to test if sending back works. If i try generating the string in CodenameOne application running on mobile device and then I send them to server and try to send them as response the result is execly the same. They are correctly printed in the server console, they are correctly stored in database, but they are returned wrong.

Comment: In both cases this is wrong. I suggest using the \u notation on both sides to verify absolutely where the data breaks. We pass localized data via ConnectionRequest to servlets very often.